# Auto-populating created_by and actionDate field with Django admin site

Tags: python, django

I have a model like this:

```
class Tour(models.Model):
   Name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
   Count=models.SmallIntegerField() 
   ActionDate=models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
   ActionUser=models.ForeignKey(User,editable=False)
   StatusType=models.ForeignKey(StatusType)
```

now I wanna auto populate current user in my Tour,so I used this code in admin.py:

```
 def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change): 
      instance = form.save(commit=False)
      instance.ActionUser = request.user
      instance.save()
      form.save_m2m()
      return instance

admin.site.register(Tour,TourAdmin)
```

it work great and it auto polulate current User in my Tour Table,but now I can't save current date in ActionDate field,I added this code to save_model but it cause error:

```
self.ActionDate=datetime.datetime.today()
```

then I tryed to override save in my Tour Model :

```
def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
      self.ActionDate=datetime.datetime.today()
      super(Tour, self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```

but this cause error,too.
what should I do to auto populate both ActionUser and ActionDate?
tnx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use [`auto_now`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now) in the field definition?